# MQTT delete published message which is not yet subscribed or recieved at subscriber

Tags: mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

Is there any way we can delete a message which has been published but not subscribed or recieved at subscriber?

Comment: Hi - is this a retained message on a specific topic? https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-8-retained-messages/

Comment: no not a retained message. But a normal message.

Comment: the connection type is persistent one (Clean session is FALSE), Retain flasg is FALSE, and QOS is 1.

Answer (score 1):

No, but if the client has never subscribed to the topic then it won't be queued for that client.

If we are talking about a message queued for a persistent subscription, then again no as this would directly contradic the QOS delivery requirements.

As of MQTT v5 it is possible to set a TTL (time to live) for a message which means if it times out before being delivered then the message will self destruct and not be delivered. But it is still not possible to reach out and remove it any other way.